# How many studies are required to assess heterogeneity of effect size in meta-analysis?

Tags: inference, meta-analysis, statistical-power

I have read that inferences on heterogeneity should be applied with caution if there are few studies. I have 6 studies for meta analysis.

- Is 6 studies sufficient to assess heterogeneity of effect sizes?
- How many studies are required to assess heterogeneity?
- What is the consequence of having an insufficient number of studies to assess heterogeneity?

Answer (score 2):

Chi-squared has low sensitivity and therefore we use 0.10 instead of the traditional 5% cutoff to determine unexpectedly high heterogeneity between the included trials. The I-squared statistic is usually used more frequently as it allows you to quantify the heterogeneity. In all cases, remember it's not only if there is or isn't statistical heterogeneity, but why there is heterogeneity. The Cochrane Handbook for Systematic Reviewers has extensive guidance on heterogeneity testing and dealing with heterogeneous data.

Comment: What is n-size for each study and state nature of effect size i.e. sample-correlations or d- statistic etc.